# R Convert dataset to a column of a second (matching) dataset

Tags: r

I have two datasets in R, and I am trying to add values of the first dataset into a single column of the second dataset. The two datasets have matching variables, based on these variables the new column should be constructed.

The first dataset looks like this:

```
    Experiment  Subject R1  R2  R3  R4
    1              1    28  29  59  55
    1              3    27  24  50  50
    1              5    30  30  61  50
    1              7    26  30  60  60
    1              10   30  30  65  65
    2              2    34  34  61  61
    2              4    25  25  49  48
    2              8    26  26  55  48
    2              9    20  20  60  60
```

The second dataset looks like this:

```
    Subject Experiment  R   NewColumn
    1          1        3   
    1          1        3   
    1          1        3   
    1          1        3   
    1          1        3   
    1          1        4   
    1          1        4   
    1          1        4   
    1          1        4   
    1          1        4   
    1          1        1   
    1          1        1   
    1          1        1   
    1          1        1   
    1          1        1   
    1          1        2
    1          1        2
    1          1        2
    1          1        2
    1          1        2
    2          2        4
    2          2        4
    2          2        4
    2          2        4
    2          2        4
    2          2        3
    2          2        3
    2          2        3
    2          2        3
    2          2        3
```

So, basicly I am trying to create a script or use a function that copies the values of R1-R4 of the first dataset into the 'NewColumn' of the second dataset, given that Experiment, Subject, and R (1-4) match.

I have tried to create a solution using loops and if statements, but unfortunately without succes.

**Edit:**

I think I should add that the second dataset contains (many) more variables (columns, which I left out for this example), is quite long (about 2000 rows) and is not ordered (Experiment, Subject and 'R' don't follow a logical order).

So my thought is, that the script should 'read' the variables 'Experiment' 'Subject' and 'R' from the second dataset, and paste the corresponding value from the first dataset (e.g. Experiment 1, Subject 1, R3) into the 'NewColumn' column. Many thanks for all of your input so far!

Any advice on how to solve this is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired output. Also, have you looked into `merge` or `match`?

Comment: The NewColumn column should read '59 59 59 59 59 55 55 55 55 55 28 28 28 ... etc.' , so based on R1-4 variables of subject 1/ experiment 1 of the first dataset.
I have looked into merge, not yet into match, will do that now. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a solution with `tidyr`/`dplyr` could be `gather(df, R, NewColumn, R1:R4) %>% mutate(R = as.numeric(sub("^R", "", R)))`

Comment: Like @docendodiscimus, it doesn't look that you need the second data set at all.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions posted below?

Comment: I am currently trying your solution, I will let you know once I got it to work :-).

Comment: Based on the example you provided, I guess it gets the expected output of `59 59 59 59 59 55 55 55 55 55 28 28 ...` in the `NewCol`

Comment: After changing the variable names it worked like a charm. I think the left_join function was primarily what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `gather` from `tidyr` to reshape the first dataset ('df1') from 'wide' to 'long' format.  We create key/val columns ('Var', 'NewCol') from the R1:R4 columns.  Then we split the 'Var' column into two new columns ('V1', 'R') using `extract`, `left_join`  with 'df2' by specifying the common columns, and `select` the columns that are needed in the output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1, Var, NewCol, R1:R4) %>% 
          extract(Var, into=c('V1', 'R'), '(.)(.)', convert=TRUE) %>%
          left_join(df2, ., by=c('Subject', 'Experiment', 'R')) %>% 
          select(-V1)
# Subject Experiment R NewCol
#1        1          1 3     59
#2        1          1 3     59
#3        1          1 3     59
#4        1          1 3     59
#5        1          1 3     59
#6        1          1 4     55
#7        1          1 4     55
#8        1          1 4     55
#9        1          1 4     55
#10       1          1 4     55
#11       1          1 1     28
#12       1          1 1     28
#13       1          1 1     28
#14       1          1 1     28
#15       1          1 1     28
#16       1          1 2     29
#17       1          1 2     29
#18       1          1 2     29
#19       1          1 2     29
#20       1          1 2     29
#21       2          2 4     61
#22       2          2 4     61
#23       2          2 4     61
#24       2          2 4     61
#25       2          2 4     61
#26       2          2 3     61
#27       2          2 3     61
#28       2          2 3     61
#29       2          2 3     61
#30       2          2 3     61
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Experiment = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Subject = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 9L), R1 = c(28L, 
27L, 30L, 26L, 30L, 34L, 25L, 26L, 20L), R2 = c(29L, 24L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 34L, 25L, 26L, 20L), R3 = c(59L, 50L, 61L, 60L, 65L, 
61L, 49L, 55L, 60L), R4 = c(55L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 65L, 61L, 48L, 
48L, 60L)), .Names = c("Experiment", "Subject", "R1", "R2", "R3", 
"R4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df2 <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Experiment = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), R = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Subject", "Experiment", 
"R"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this ?

```
library(reshape)
df<- data.frame(Experiment=c(1,1),Subject=c(1,3),R1=c(28,27),R2=c(29,24),R3=c(59,50),R4=c(55,50))

> df
  Experiment Subject R1 R2 R3 R4
1          1       1 28 29 59 55
2          1       3 27 24 50 50

dfc <- melt(df,id=c("Experiment","Subject"))
dfc # New Data
> dfc
  Experiment Subject variable value
1          1       1       R1    28
2          1       3       R1    27
3          1       1       R2    29
4          1       3       R2    24
5          1       1       R3    59
6          1       3       R3    50
7          1       1       R4    55
8          1       3       R4    50
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. I added an edit to my original question (and am currently trying out akrun's suggestion posted below).